# Pytorch tutorial LSTM

Tags: neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

I was trying to implement [the exercise](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html#exercise-augmenting-the-lstm-part-of-speech-tagger-with-character-level-features) about Sequence Models and Long-Short Term Memory Networks with Pytorch. The idea is to add an LSTM part-of-speech tagger character-level features but I can't seem to work it out. They gave as a hint that there should be two LSTMs involved, one that will output a character level representation and another one that will be in charge of predicting the Part-of-speech tag. I just can't figure out how to loop over the words level (in a sentence) and over the character (in each word of a sentence) and implement it in the forward function. Does anyone know how to do it ? Or encounter a similar situation ?

Here is my code:

```python
class LSTMTaggerAug(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, embedding_dim_words, embedding_dim_chars, hidden_dim_words, hidden_dim_chars, vocab_size, tagset_size, charset_size):
    super(LSTMTaggerAug, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_dim_words = hidden_dim_words
    self.hidden_dim_chars = hidden_dim_chars
    self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim_words)
    self.char_embeddings = nn.Embedding(charset_size, embedding_dim_chars)
    self.lstm_char = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim_chars, hidden_dim_chars)
    self.lstm_words = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim_words + hidden_dim_chars, hidden_dim_words)
    self.hidden2tag = nn.Linear(hidden_dim_words, tagset_size)
    self.hidden_char = self.init_hidden(c=False)
    self.hidden_words = self.init_hidden(c=True)

def init_hidden(self, c=True):
    if c:
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim_words)),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim_words)))
    else:
        return (autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim_chars)),
                autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_dim_chars)))


def forward(self, sentence, words):
    # embeds = self.word_embeddings(sentence)
    for ix, word in enumerate(sentence):
        chars = words[ix]
        char_embeds = self.char_embeddings(chars)
        lstm_char_out, self.hidden_char = self.lstm_char(
            char_embeds.view(len(chars), 1, -1), self.hidden_char)
        char_rep = lstm_char_out[-1]
        embeds = self.word_embeddings(word)
        embeds_cat = torch.cat((embeds, char_rep), dim=1)
        lstm_out, self.hidden_words = self.lstm_words(embeds_cat, self.hidden_words)
        tag_space = self.hidden2tag(lstm_out.view(1, -1))
        tag_score = F.log_softmax(tag_space, dim=1)
        if ix==0:
            tag_scores = tag_score
        else:
            tag_scores = torch.cat((tag_scores, tag_score), 0)

    return tag_scores
```

Comment: It was very easy to find implementations for the [previous exercise](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html#exercise-computing-word-embeddings-continuous-bag-of-words) (see [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nlp-in-pytorch-tutorial/883)). The closest I can find for the exercise in question is [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/implementation-augmenting-the-lstm-part-of-speech-tagger-with-character-level-features/10221), and responses are conflicting...

Comment: @DylanF Thank you ! Yes I saw those implementations and had the same impressions as you. Rather confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The most naive way to do it according to your description would be to take a sentence `s` stripped of punctuation. Then split it into words:

```
words = s.split()
```

Take your first character level lstm, `LSTMc` and apply it to every word individually to encode the words (use the last output-state of the lstm to encode the word):

```
encoded_words = []
for word in words:
    state = state_0

    for char in word:
        h, state = LSTMc(one_hot_encoding(char), state)
    encoded_words.append(h)
```

After you've encoded the words, you pass word-level the part of speech tagger lstm `LSTMw` on the encoded words:

```
state = statew_0
parts_of_speech = []
for enc_word in encoded_words:
    pos, state = LSTMw(enc_word, state)
    parts_of_speech.append(pos)
```

Comment: Thank you !!
The only problem I see is that the element in encoded_words might not have the same size. And furthermore how do you keep track of 'encoded_words' and the labels (initial POS) ?

Comment: Yes, good point. It is probably better to take the last output `h` to be the encoded word, let me change that.

Comment: When you train your model you have as input sequence of words and corresponding labels as output. Here I am just saying that the `encoded_words` might not be aligned with the labels. Thanks to your useful feedback I was able to correct my model, if you have some time you can look [here](https://gist.github.com/jhumigas/7b984c96d89f6f53e7ea3d0afa4f4b09) @patapouf_ai

Comment: I don't understand how it would not be aligned. The first word corresponds to the first POS and so on. They are always kept in the order which they appear.

Comment: Indeed, you're right ! I have just thought about it. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166301/discussion-between-david-and-patapouf-ai).